# Get path to local file in chrome

Tags: javascript, google-chrome

I want to be able to get a list of files (mp3 files) and store them into my web app so the next time the user comes the list can be reproduced again.

I am getting the files using and `<input>` and then converting the returned value with `URL.createObjectURL()`.

It of course works when I load the file for the first time, but when I reload the app and try to use the saved urls (blob) it throw an error: `net::ERR_FILE_NOT_FOUND`;

Is there a way to do this?, maybe asking for permissions in chrome or similar?

Edit:

I am not using any remote server, all is (and will always) been done locally.

I do not care about the file content, I just want to have the path to be able to assign it to an `<audio>` source.

Edit2:

What I do to get the src is `URL.createObjectURL(file)` where File is the file I got from the `<input>` `onchange` event.

Comment: you can store the object's dataurl in localstorage and check for it when the page is reloaded.

Comment: @Iwrestledabearonce. I store it in local storage but after a reload the blob is not valid.

Comment: you can't sore a blob in localstorage. convert it to a datauri before storing it and then convert the datauri back to a blob when you pull it out. just google "blob to datauri" or "datauri to blob" there are functions available.

Comment: All the options I see about that include an `FileReader`, that is saving the content of the file. I do not want to do that. I just want to stream an mp3 file from the local file system.

Comment: FileReader isn't just for actual files, it also reads and converts blobs.

Comment: What I mean is that it gets the complete blob file (for example a 2MB mp3 https://i.imgur.com/YyB2xXh.png) that means it needs to put it into memory and save it in local storage to post load (if it is a playlist with 20 songs it gets ugly)

Comment: you are right. it's an ugly solution and will only hold a small playlist but that is the only option you have using a browser. you might consider using electron instead which uses javascript and html to build actual desktop applications, which can give you access to the user's hard drive.

Answer (score 0):

For security reasons, your web browser will not be able to access your local files unless when using an `input` field with type `file`. One thing you can do is cache the files content on your server or persist them if the files are uploaded. You will not be able to access local files when deployed and not on localhost anymore.

There seem to be a way of accessing it using this `path\to\your\chrome\installation\chrome.exe --allow-file-access-from-files`, but I haven't tested personally.